# Getting QGis in Anaconda for MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, qgis

I am on MacOS 10.13.3 and I am using the latest Anaconda to have python 3 on my machine.  For work I need to use [QGis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which for MacOS is packaged [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).

Unfortunately the MacOS binary must be run with python 3 from [python.org](https://www.python.org/), which I find immensely annoying since I do not have disk space to waste for duplicates.  I noticed that Anaconda provides the latest QGis for Linux only, and I was wondering how trivial or non trivial would it be to get the QGis source and prepare it of MacOS Anaconda (or maybe it is simpler to port the Linux Anaconda QGis?).

Keeping in mind that I do not actually use python that much -- I mostly use Spyder to run a few scripts to produce images -- do I have any chances of successfully porting QGis to MacOS Anaconda?  I do not have the time to become an expert in python/anaconda management.